# 11.04 boot takes over 4 minutes

Tags: 11.04, boot, xubuntu

I did a fresh install of Xubuntu 11.04 on a clean disk. CPU Athlon 64 X2 3600+, 1 GiB of RAM. The machine is about 5 years old and works like a charm normally.
Buuut: The normal boot takes about 4 minutes with XU 11.04, including a 3 minute pause time where the machine does nothing (see [bootchart 1](https://imgur.com/bTAIe&hTLfQl), [kern.log](http://pastebin.com/7E8uMkmV) (see lines around 742). If I add "noapic nolapic acpi=off" the boot time is reduced a lot, but there's still a pause of approximately half a minute (see second bootchart image in above link). I also tried disabling legacy USB support in BIOS (didn't change anything).

Especially since there's still a lot of pause in the second boot I'm wondering if there's anything else to help it.

Secondly the first bootchart is making me wonder how the times in there are given. It states the boot process finished after less than a minute which obviously is wrong if you look in the kern.log. Is there something that makes the system like completely frozen in that period of time where it does nothing so bootchart can't even account the time?

Regards,
Chris

Comment: Looks like there is something really wrong with your Xorg; it is sitting there burning up cpu for a long time before it actually initializes the display.

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Comment: Your kern.log shows an oops related to the sound card. It is a longshot, but you can try disabling the faulty driver by creating `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-for-now.conf` with one line in it: `blacklist snd_hda_intel` and rebooting. You can remove the file afterwards.

Comment: Seems like blacklisting the sound module did the trick. Boots in about 30 seconds to desktop. Thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like blacklisting the sound module did the trick. Boots in about 30 seconds to desktop. Thanks a lot =) – Christian Aug 2 '11 at 18:20

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you have 64-bit XU 11.04 installed instead of 32-bit.

- 64-Bit over 4 Gig of RAM or more (which you do not have) and a 64-bit processor(which you do have )

Without having 4 Gigs of RAM or more your system will be extremely slow and sluggish.

- 32-Bit 4 or 3.512 Gig of RAM or Less (which you have 1 Gig of RAM) standard single core 32-Bit processor or better (which you have Athlon 64 X2 3600+ ) your 64-bit processor will clock down to 32-bit

With 32-bit XU 11.04 your system should run alot better if not then I recommend either downgrading to 10.10 or upgrading your video card (nvidia or ati  preferably)

Comment: I have never experienced this supposed slowdown because I installed 64bit on a system with less then 4GB ram. As a matter of fact, the system I use daily has 3GB ram, 64bit Athlon processor, and runs Xubuntu 64bit development release.

Comment: ok fair enough . My mistake poor choice of words. I should have put "Without having 4 Gigs of RAM or more your system could (instead of will) be extremely slow and/or sluggish." but I corrected that in my statement.